# Form with 2 submit buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, window.open

I have one form with 2 submit buttons. The form generates a URL.

The 2 outputs of the form are:

1. It writes a URL to a hidden div which displays when they click the Preview button, and
2. It launches the same URL in a new window when they click the Open button.

I am able to write to the hidden DIV, so the Preview function works perfectly.

My problem is:

I am not able to get the window.open function to work correctly with the Open button.

When I click the button, I get "http://www.my_current_domain.com/undefined" when I have initially entered a different domain in the "firstfield" input area.

Here is a sample of my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() {
        var firstfield = document.getElementById('firstfield').value;
        ...repeated.. for 7 more fields...
        /* Base 64 Encode the username and password */
        var UserPassword64Encoded = User + ":" + Password;
        var UserPassword64Encoded = btoa(UserPassword64Encoded);
        /* here is where I assemble the URL */
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = firstfield + "?some_static_info=" +
        ... repeated 7 more times...;
        document.getElementById('results').style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Here is a sample of my form:

```
<form name="myForm" onSubmit="return myfunction();">
    <input  type="text" id="firstfield" name="firstfield"/>
    ... repreated 7 more times...
    <input type="submit" value="Preview"/>
    <input type="submit" onClick="window.open(myForm.results)" value="Open"/>
</form>
/* Hidden DIV */
<div id="results">
</div>
```

I've been working at just this one issue for 2 days now and am now going in circles.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Best Regards,
Dennis Hall

Comment: results isn't part of the form, so I am confused by myForm.results also you should attach event handlers to these DOM elements instead of inline onsubmit and onclick.

Adding "name" attributes to your submit buttons will allowed your submitted form switch between the 2 user actions.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_name.asp

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, to properly format code please indent the code by 4 spaces. There is a button in the editor `{}`.

Comment: If you mean in the second submit button, I agree.

Comment: @mikeclagg how would you recommend I write the submit button to open the new window?

Comment: @DaseinA I had tried adding conditions in myFunction() but it breaks the Preview part of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get 'results' in the manner you're attempting. You'll need to try getting it via the ID reference, something like the following:

```
<form name="myForm" onSubmit="return myfunction();">
    <input  type="text" id="firstfield" name="firstfield"/>
    ... repreated 7 more times...
    <input type="submit" value="Preview"/>
    <input type="submit" onClick="window.open(document.getElementById('firstField').value + '/' + document.getElementById('results').value);" value="Open"/>
</form>
/* Hidden DIV */
<div id="results">
</div>
```

**EDIT:** And to make sure window.open doesn't think its a relative URL, ensure it starts with a protocol, eg http:// or https://.

Comment: Thanks David W, that is partly working. Now I do not get "/undefined" but do still get my current domain in front of it (probably because of the innerHTML, but I do not know how to change the results from innerHTML for the second button.

Comment: @Dennis - I think I fixed it but it's a quick change - the idea is basically the same - just to grab the firstField element into your string that you pass to window.open

Comment: It sounds like your suggesting that I only use the content entered in the FirstField item of the form and launch that only. The problem is that I am assembling a URL from 8 fields and static information between them. I need them all to launch the window. Here is my project URL so you can see what I mean: http://learning-templates.com/tincan-launcher-bak1.html

Comment: I just tried your adjustment and it no longer opens a new window.

Comment: Apologies @Dennis I did overlook how you were using *all* of those fields.  Give me a sec and I'll take a further look.

Comment: Hey @David W, I really appreciate the help! I reverted the project back to your first suggestion because this IS the closest I gotten in 2 days.

Comment: Okay I think my brain is in gear to help. If you don't prefix the string passed to window.open with a protocol, the browser (typically) treats it as a relative URL from the opener - your current location. The solution, then, would be to ensure that "Launch URL" starts with either "http://" or "https://"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, YOU GOT IT!!! :) I'll comment the form to indicate the user must include the protocol for the first and second fields. The final solution was to change <input type="submit" onClick="window.open(document.getElementById('results').innerHTML);" value="Open" />

Comment: Awesome. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Hi again @DavidW I've now been working with the tincan-launcher and it works great as we last left it, however, I'm wondering if the window.open button could open the generated URL in a DIV. What have set up is another DIV whose CSS is "display:none" and when the user clicks the <input type="submit" onClick="window.open(document.getElementById('results').innerHTML);" value="Open Launch URL in New Window" tabindex="10"/> button, I would like that to open in the currently hidden div. I've been trying to do this already by having multiple onClick events, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Dennis. I don't think you can really target a "div" as the host for a URL. If you really want to do something like that, you'd probably need to embed an IFRAME into the DIV, and then set the src property of the IFRAME to the URL generated by your existing code, which then means you're not using window.open anymore.

Comment: Hi David W, I had thought of that, however, the content of the URL will "most likely" vary in height and width. I've also asked this question in a new question (thinking you would not be available to help). So disregard any new related question from me. I'll mess with it more and if I do find a solution I'll update this post as well as my other question.