# Open generated URL in DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script that generates a URL by assembling form inputs using a JavaScript function. Via the form submit buttons the URL can be previewed as text in a DIV named "preview" and opened in a new window.

Everything works, however, I would like the window.open function of that submit button to open the webpage in a DIV instead.

My button code to open the URL in a new window is:

```
<input type="submit" onClick="window.open(document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML);" value="Open Launch URL in New Window" tabindex="10"/>
```

...where preview is the DIV ID where the user previews the URL as text.

I've tried to use multiple onClick events but that does not work.

Comment: So like an iframe? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: Thanks for getting back Austin. Like an iFrame, yes, but the content will "most likely" vary in height and width so I will need to resize the webpage to fit in the DIV. I don't think you can resize a webpage in a iFrame, only set the frame size.

Comment: Resolved in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852807/form-with-2-submit-buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `<object>` with the `data` property set to the url. Looks like:

```
<div id="preview">
  <object id="previewWindow">
  </object>
</div>

<input type="submit" onClick="document.getElementById('previewWindow').data = document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML;" value="Open Launch URL in New Window" tabindex="10"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost with this solution. I understand the Object in the div, but my buttons currently has the onClick function sending the existing 'results' to a new window. So would the JS replace the onClick function in my button, or would I create a new function then onClick that new function? If yes for the new function, would your reference to ".data = yourUrl" become ".data = results"?

Comment: @Dennis Simply add this line to your `onClick` function. See my update, I included your code

Comment: Small Update: I have it back to where my preview works, but the button to open the URL in a div will not work. In order to keep my original preview functionality working, I did some rework and now have it setup so the open URL setup now mimics your code above. Unfortunately, the button does not do anything that I am able to trace. To see for yourself, here is a link to my original project: http://learning-templates.com/tincan-launcher.html and here is a link to this version: http://learning-templates.com/tincan-launcher_v2.html If you just enter a URL in the first field you can see the results